# how to run each sampler in parallel with same csv data

Tags: api, jmeter, load, jmeter-5.0, threadgroup

Need to run these sampler request in parallel with same csv file provided
[image: Thread plan]
[image: Thread Group]

CSV have LN,Userid columns that with three values
I want to run all three samplers at same time for each values. So total would be 9 requests ( 3 values ins CSV)

Submit1|Submit2|Submit3 (all should run in parallel for same userid's in csv)

```
(for value Userid1) |  for value Userid2 | Userid3
Submit1             |  Submit1           | Submit1 
Submit2             |  Submit2           | Submit2
Submit3             |  Submit3           | Submit3
```

Answer (score 0):

Did able to manage by setting csv for all Threads and Recycle on EOF = True and Stop at EOF to False.

When used No of threads to 3, It reaches 18 instead was expecting 9 only